# How is strace decoding system calls?

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel, system-calls, strace

Strace is a very powerful tool, I know it is implemented with ptrace, this is easy to understand.

But I think the best thing about it is that it can decode all system calls, 
display the names of all the parameters, including the data structure, even the macro can be displayed, it is amazing!

How did it do it???

Comment: Painstaking implementation in code.